# Can I use a SSD in a socket m.2 2230 for WLAN

Tags: ssd

I have an HP Pavilion 27-a001la all-in-one (tech specs [here](https://support.hp.com/cl-es/document/c05240074)), and I'd like to add an SSD drive (it has a 5400 rpm HDD). The motherboard (Saipan-4GF) has one "socket m.2 2230 for WLAN". Can I use that socket to install an SSD, and if so, which one would you recommend? The idea is to keep both disks, and then transfer the OS (win10) + apps to the SSD and keep the HDD as file repository.

Answer (score 1):

If the SSD key is the same as the slot key, it should be as easy to buy the ssd, put it in your laptop and transferring the partitions. But you probalby can't do that, and if you can, I can't make any ssd recommendations because I don't know the key.